# Mercurial undo commit

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Is it possible to change the branch for some last commits ?

```
server  local  desired
           |       |
          13      13
           |       |
          12      12
           |       |
          11      11
           |     /
  10      10    10
  |        |
```

*Explanation:*

I work in the Mercurial's `default` branch on a SiteV1. The current revision is 10 (local and server).

I started to work to a brad new version of SiteV2... Unfortunately I commited *locally* this SiteV2 on the same `default` branch: `rev.11`, `rev.12`, `rev.13`... so locally I am on `rev.13+` (13 with some modifications)...

On the server is still `rev.10`

*I would like to commit on the server all revisions from `10` to a new branch `SiteV2`... in order that my commits rev.11....rev 14 be on this new branch., theh commit all on the server.*  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

As you didn't propagate any changes yet, it's simple. You'll need to make use of the `rebase` extension which you might need to enable in your config file (it's not active by default but shipped with mercurial, though):

```
hg up -r10
hg branch NEWBRANCH
hg commit -m "New branch NEWBRANCH"
hg rebase -s12 -d.
```

We need to make a small detour and commit an empty commit (and I do believe it's a needless limitation of rebase). We first graft (copy) the 1st changeset as simply rebasing everything will fail. But with the first commit in the new branch present, we can simply move (=rebase) the remaining ones.

A word of caution: `rebase` is a history altering operations. Make a (local) clone of your local repository before you attempt this, so that you have a backup copy of it, should anything go wrong (like typing wrong version to rebase or so).

EDIT: Simplified steps based on the hint given by Lazy Badger. Thanks!

Comment: Lazy Badger, can you elaborate? The commits already exist... so what shall be committed? Something new which the user also doesn't want? Or can I commit an empty changeset after branching? Then it would simplify it.

Comment: yes, commit for just opening branch, without content